# DevForce Classic and is SQL Time datatype supported

Tags: sql-server, devforce

Before I start using time datatype in SQL I wanted to make sure that it was compatible with Ideablade DevForce Classic v3.8.5.0

It's an older product but time has been out for a while (pun intended) so I'm assuming it's supported.  I notice that in the mapper it shows both the source datatype and datatype as string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but DevForce Classic does not support the Time data type, nor other date-time related data types introduced way back in SQL Server 2008.